# Git LFS still diff-ing files?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I was under the impression that the purpose of Git LFS was to *not* diff binary files.

In a simple test, I have a test repo with 2 files: an 8mb `music.mp3` file, and a 'textFile.txt' file that's only a couple of kb.

I then run these commands:

```
git init
git lfs install
git lfs track '*.mp3'
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

Reasonably, the size of my git repo goes up to around 8mb, as with the way Git LFS works it still has to store the file. The issue appears when I replace that 8mb `music.mp3` file with a 30mb `music.mp3` file. I run the same code

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Changed music"
```

but now my repo jumps up to 38mb! It appears as if it's still storing the different versions of the binary file, even though I have Git LFS installed. Is there something I'm missing?

I was hoping to be able to use Git for an upcoming game project, but if I can't get LFS to work I may have to figure something else out.

Comment: Do you need to manually track .gitattributes like it says in the [doc](https://git-lfs.github.com/)?

Comment: How are you measuring the size of your repo?

Comment: @Useless "git add --all" adds all files. I double checked and .gitattributes is being successfully tracks

Comment: @bk2204 I am using Right Click > Properties in Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

When you add a large file for Git LFS, that large file is stored in your repository under a subdirectory of the `.git` directory.  So if you have added one 8 MB file with Git LFS, and then added another 30 MB file with Git LFS, those files will live in your local repository at least until you push them somewhere else and your `.git` directory will be 38 MB bigger.

This is normal and expected, because Git LFS tracks every version of every file you commit, just like Git does.  However, Git LFS doesn't compress the data because (a) many large files, like MP3s, are already compressed and won't compress well and (b) you usually don't store many copies of them on your system at once, instead downloading only the versions you need to check out.

Git LFS can prune data which is no longer needed on the system with `git lfs prune`, but that data must have been pushed elsewhere.  Otherwise, of course, pruning things would result in data loss.  In addition, data is usually kept for a certain number of days, since data that is recently used is likely to be used again.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused as to what Git LFS does. I thought it allowed you to add binary files to your git repo, but not version them. Git appears to track binary files the exact same way without git LFS tracking, so I'm really struggling to get the point of Git LFS

Comment: No, Git LFS does track and version files.  The benefit is that you can clone and work with a repository but you only need to have the large files for the current checkout and anything you haven't pushed.  The rest of the large files, while versioned, are stored on the server and downloaded only on demand.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know that. Misunderstanding on my part. Do you know of any way to not version binary files, but still work with repos?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tooling, other than maybe using an asset server (e.g., Artifactor) of some sort.